# Why does Class.getSuperclass() sometimes return Object.class?

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, superclass

According to the [Class.getSuperclass() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()):

> Returns the Class representing the superclass of the entity (class,
>   interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class. If this
>   Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive
>   type, or void, then null is returned.

But I'm sometimes seeing `Object.class` being returned (using jdk1.7.0_45) - so am having to check for it separately:

```
final Class<?> superclass = modelClass.getSuperclass();
if ((superclass != null) && (Object.class != superclass)) {
     // Do stuff with superclasses other than Object.
}
```

Is this a Java bug? Is there a better way of checking whether `superclass` is an `Object`?

Comment: In your scenario, everything is an `instanceof` an `Object`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I won't go into detail but reflection is being used to loop through all methods of a class and recursively all its ancestors except for Object.

Comment: If you don't go in to detail, then I'm not sure how I can be of assistance. If I know your intent, perhaps there is a different way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: The detail was left out because it isn't relevant to the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation says that if your class is `java.lang.Object`, then its `getSuperclass` is going to return `null`. In other words, if you do this

```
Class objSuper = Object.class.getSuperclass();
```

then `objSuper` would be `null`; this is precisely what's happening ([demo](http://ideone.com/8oSQz8)).

It appears, however, that your `modelClass` is *not* `java.lang.Object`, and it is also not a primitive or an interface. Therefore, returning `java.lang.Object` makes perfect sense, because all classes implicitly inherit from it.

Comment: Ah now I understand. Have now added the first sentence of the documentation to the question. There are two "Class"es referred to in that sentence and I'd wrongly thought the second sentence thinking it was referring to the first not the second. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

The *this Class* in the documentation is referring to the caller of the `getSuperclass()` method as far as I understand it.

So if the caller is either the `Object` class or a primitive type / interface the superclass returned will be `null` which makes total sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find out if `Object` is a **direct** parent of your class, you can use

```
System.out.println(YourObject.class.getSuperclass() == Object.class);
```

Otherwise you should know that at the end each object inherits `Object` class. Instead of `Object` class itself, so `.getSuperclass()` will return `null`.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this. :D